# Az Devops Commands Failing in Azure Pipelines (Classic)

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-cli

I am at a loss as to why I cannot run a basic az devops command in an Azure Pipeline using the Classic template.

So basically, I have two Powershell tasks defined for my Classic pipeline and these are:

[image]

Task 1: Login to my Azure DevOps organisation using the following commands:

```
$mytoken = "My_PersonalAccessToken"
echo $mytoken "|" az devops login --organization https://dev.azure.com/OrganisationName
```

Task 2: List My Azure DevOps Projects

```
az devops project list
```

**Task 1** works perfectly and login is confirmed as successful.

**Task 2** however fails and displays the below error in the pipeline output:

```
 Before you can run Azure DevOps commands, you need to run the login command(az login if using AAD/MSA identity else az devops login if using PAT token) to setup credentials.  Please see https://aka.ms/azure-devops-cli-auth for more information.
```

[image]

What could I be doing wrong? Would really appreciate some help, although I must emphasise again that my pipeline uses the Classic template and any proposed solution must be tailored for that.

Mind you, when I run these very same commands in my Powershell ISE editor, both run perfectly and I get all my Azure DevOps projects listed.

Comment: Have you had a chance to check the provided solution(s)?

Comment: Yes, @BhargaviAnnadevara I just did and it worked absolutely perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that piping PAT on StdIn to `az devops login` is failing. However, an even better approach IMHO would be to set the `AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT` environment variable, and not use `az devops login` at all. :)

Pipeline variables:

[image]

Tasks:

[image]

Check [Sign in with a personal access token (PAT)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/log-in-via-pat?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows#use-the-azure_devops_ext_pat-environment-variable) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a product issue recently, as the Azure CLI should work, it worked for me last month, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69179255/pass-variable-group-as-dictionary-to-python-script/69206727#69206727).

For now, if you want to list the projects, you could call the REST API [Projects - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/Projects/List?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) directly in PowerShell task.

```
$MyPat = '<PAT>'
$B64Pat = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(":$MyPat"))
$URL = 'https://dev.azure.com/orgname/_apis/projects?api-version=6.0'
$header = @{
    'Authorization' = 'Basic ' + $B64Pat
    'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
}

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $URL -Headers $header| ConvertTo-Json
```

[image]